# Error launching job using mrjob on Hadoop

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, mrjob

I am new to hadoop and mrjob and this book really helped me a lot to learn. I was trying to run mrSVM.py on hadoop as it works fine locally.

But I ran the following command:`python mrSVM.py -r hadoop kickStart.txt`
and it gives the following error:

```
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
creating tmp directory /tmp/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574
writing wrapper script to /tmp/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/setup-wrapper.sh
Using Hadoop version 2.5.0
Copying local files into hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/
HADOOP: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
HADOOP: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
HADOOP: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
HADOOP: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-manvendra/mapred/staging/manvendra1365509453/.staging/job_local1365509453_0001
HADOOP: Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist: /tmp/hadoop-manvendra/mapred/staging/manvendra1365509453/.staging/job_local1365509453_0001/archives/mrjob.tar.gz#mrjob.tar.gz
HADOOP: Streaming Command Failed!
Job failed with return code 512: ['/home/manvendra/hadoop-2.5.0/bin/hadoop', 'jar', '/home/manvendra/hadoop-2.5.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.5.0.jar', '-files', 'hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/setup-wrapper.sh#setup-wrapper.sh,hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/mrSVM.py#mrSVM.py', '-archives', 'hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/mrjob.tar.gz#mrjob.tar.gz', '-input', 'hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/kickStart.txt', '-output', 'hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/step-output/1', '-mapper', 'sh -e setup-wrapper.sh python mrSVM.py --step-num=0 --mapper', '-reducer', 'sh -e setup-wrapper.sh python mrSVM.py --step-num=0 --reducer']
Scanning logs for probable cause of failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mrSVM.py", line 81, in <module>
MRsvm.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob-0.4.3_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/job.py", line 462, in run
mr_job.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob-0.4.3_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/job.py", line 480, in execute
super(MRJob, self).execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob-0.4.3_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/launch.py", line 147, in execute
self.run_job()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob-0.4.3_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/launch.py", line 210, in run_job
runner.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob-0.4.3_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/runner.py", line 464, in run
self._run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob-0.4.3_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 239, in _run
self._run_job_in_hadoop()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob-0.4.3_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 369, in _run_job_in_hadoop
raise CalledProcessError(returncode, step_args)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/manvendra/hadoop-2.5.0/bin/hadoop', 'jar', '/home/manvendra/hadoop-2.5.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.5.0.jar', '-files', 'hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/setup-wrapper.sh#setup-wrapper.sh,hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/mrSVM.py#mrSVM.py', '-archives', 'hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/mrjob.tar.gz#mrjob.tar.gz', '-input', 'hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/files/kickStart.txt', '-output', 'hdfs:///user/manvendra/tmp/mrjob/mrSVM.manvendra.20140818.075925.908574/step-output/1', '-mapper', 'sh -e setup-wrapper.sh python mrSVM.py --step-num=0 --mapper', '-reducer', 'sh -e setup-wrapper.sh python mrSVM.py --step-num=0 --reducer']' returned non-zero exit status 512
```

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem with Hadoop 2.x & mrjob. Please make the following changes, format your namenode, restart your hadoop instance + yarn and things should work.

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
 <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/tmp</value>
      <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
 <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/tmp</value>
      <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property> 
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name> 
    <value>yarn</value> 
  </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>128</value>
        <description>Minimum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>2048</value>
        <description>Maximum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <description>The minimum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests lower than this won't take effect, and the specified value will get allocated the minimum.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>2</value>
        <description>The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests higher than this won't take effect, and will get capped to this value.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>4096</value>
        <description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>4</value>
        <description>Number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
      <description>shuffle service that needs to be set for Map Reduce to run </description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Then run:

```
hdfs namenode -format
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

Cheers,

Thusjanthan Kubendranathan